# MySql query not in working in PHP but works in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

At first I'm sorry for posting duplicate question I always try to find answers and never to ask. But nothing solved my problem. I have a MySql DB with table named `data`. I cannot change the table name. When I execute `` SELECT * FROM `data` `` or `SELECT * FROM data` in phpMyAdmin, the query works correctly but when I execute it in PHP script the `query()` returns `false`

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'pswd', 'dbname');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('connection error');
}
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `data`");

var_dump($result);

echo "-".$conn->error."-";
```

I have looked at these questions:

[Mysql query works in phpmyadmin but not in php (due to date)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912833/mysql-query-works-in-phpmyadmin-but-not-in-php-due-to-date)

[Mysql query works in Phpmyadmin but not works in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410792/mysql-query-works-in-phpmyadmin-but-not-works-in-php)

[MySQL query working in phpmyadmin but not in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45388357/mysql-query-working-in-phpmyadmin-but-not-in-php)

and some others...

Comment: Have you checked [mysqli_error](http://php.net/mysqli_error)?

Comment: returns emty string ""

Comment: That seems unlikely. Where and how are you using it?

Comment: check error by $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `data`") or die ($conn->error);

Comment: share full code...

Comment: updated full code

Comment: when i try to select any other table in this db it is working, i have problem only with this one table

Comment: i know that it is reserved keyword but i cannot change the table name, there is already application for pc in c++ using this db and table data and i do not have access to that c++ code

Comment: chaged to ``$conn->query("SELECT * FROM `data`") or die("-".$conn->error."-");`` returns empty string => "--"

Comment: `data` is a keyword but not a reserved keyword  - should be within backticks in sql statements for safety.

Comment: should it be problem with some DB settings in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your replies I've got some idea what to try next.I've created copy of the table on my own server and tried changing data types. One of data types in original table is set as JSON, when i changed it to TEXT it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result ="SELECT * FROM `data`";
$row=mysqli_query($conn,$result);
while($row_result=$row->fetch_assoc())
print_r($row_result);
```

Comment: the `$row` variable is set to false as result of mysqli_query

Comment: you can fetch data with while loop i check it is ok

Comment: no i can't, when i var_dump($row) i get returned bool(false)

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.